# Gorilla/mux request DTO builder

Tags: go

I got tired of having to extract the provided input from the requests manually so I made a library with which I can extract the values from the request a build a given DTO. The idea is to create structs which to fill out by coordinating through tags. Then, once the struct is filled out, we can pass the struct to the validator package, for example, and see if the values are there are valid. This is the repository: https://github.com/Enthys/mux-dto

For not it only supports `application/json`, `text/xml`, `application/xml` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as `content-types`, and for the `query` arguments `arrays` are not supported. Have not gotten to that yet.

Would really appreciate any feedback.

In a real world application the library would be used in the following manner:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/Enthys/mux_dto"
    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "golang.org/x/exp/slog"
)

type UpdateUserRequest struct {
    ID   int    `from:"param,id" validate:"required"`
    Name string `json:"name" validate:"required,min=6"`
    Age  int    `json:"age" validate:"required, min=18"`
}

type GetUserPosts struct {
    UserID int `from:"param,id" validate:"required"`
    Page   int `from:"query,page" validate:"min=0"`
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    v := validator.New()
    router.Path("/users/{id}").Methods("PATCH").HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var req UpdateUserRequest
        if err := mux_dto.Build(r, &req); err != nil {
            slog.Error("failed to parse request. Error: %w", err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            w.Write([]byte(`{"error": "invalid request"}`))
            return
        }

        if err := v.Struct(req); err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            w.Write([]byte(`{"error": "invalid request"}`))
            return
        }

        // Proceed . . .
    })

    router.Path("/users/{id}/posts").Methods("GET").HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var req GetUserPosts
        if err := mux_dto.Build(r, &req); err != nil {
            slog.Error("failed to parse request. Error: %w", err)
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            w.Write([]byte(`{"error": "invalid request"}`))
            return
        }

        if err := v.Struct(req); err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            w.Write([]byte(`{"error": "invalid request"}`))
            return
        }

        // Proceed . . .
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8888", router); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```